# Poor performance when UPDATE multiple arrays of multiple rows in a table

Tags: sql-server

I am working on an old classic ASP application with SQL Server Express.

Users will edit and submit item's information in quotation from HTML table and update SQL Server [quotation_details] table.

There are about few hundred rows of items to update at once.
When I use INSERT statement to add records, the performance is OK.
BUT when use UPDATE to update few hundred of rows that item_ID matched, the performance is poor.

This is the code:

```
for i=0 to Ubound(arrItemID)<br>
 if Trim(arrItemID(i))<>"" then<br>
  Sqlstr = "UPDATE [Quotation_Details] SET "<br>
  Sqlstr = Sqlstr & "Unit_Price=" & arrUnitPrice(i) & ","<br>
  Sqlstr = Sqlstr & "Unit='" & Trim(arrUnit(i)) & "'"<br>
  Sqlstr = Sqlstr & " WHERE Item_ID=" & arrItemID(i)<br>
  Sqlstr = Sqlstr & " AND Quot_ID=" & F_Quot_ID<br>
  Dconn.Execute Sqlstr<br>
  Dconn.close<br>
 end if<br>
next<br>
```

Comment: Do you know if the table Quotation_Details has an index on Item_ID and Quot_ID?   How many records are in the table? Depending on how many records are in the table, it could take time for the query to find the records to update but with an insert, it doesn't have to find any records.  There are really a ton of other reasons it could go slow (disk speed, CPU, RAM, etc), but this would be my basic first troubleshooting step.

Comment: You need to start using parameterized queries immediately if not sooner. My friend [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) loves code like this that is exposed to sql injection.

Comment: To be honest I am not surprised the performance is less than ideal. You are updating your table row by row. You might consider using table valued parameters to a stored procedure and you can do mass updates with a join very fast.

Comment: @ElementZero
The table Quotation_Details has a column "ID" as index and the table now has about 200K rows of records. SQL runs in dedicated server with 4 core CPU, 16GB RAM with RAID1

Comment: @SeanLange
How to use " table valued parameters to a stored procedure" that mass update with join? Would you share more on it? Many thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I have fixed with using temp table and inner join update, many thanks